# How fix 'Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.' inside gatsby-config and Gatsby-node.js

Tags: typescript, gatsby, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, typescript-eslintparser

In my eslintrc.js I have a.o:

```
extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  globals: {
    __PATH_PREFIX__: true,
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
      typescript: true,
      tsx: true,
    },
  },
```

In the root of my Gatsby project I have `gatsby-config.js` and `gatsby-config.js`. In the beginning of the file I get a `ESLint` linting error:

> Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for
> @typescript-eslint/parser. The file does not match your project
> config: gatsby-config.js. The file must be included in at least one of
> the projects provided.eslint

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `include` array in your `.tsconfig` to include all files you want to lint, as you can see from [the docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/parser/README.md#configuration):

> Note that if this setting is specified and `createDefaultProgram` is
> not, you must only lint files that are included in the projects as
> defined by the provided `tsconfig.json` files. If your existing
> configuration does not include all of the files you would like to
> lint, you can create a separate `tsconfig.eslint.json` as follows:
>
> ```
> {
>   // extend your base config so you don't have to redefine your compilerOptions
>   "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
>   "include": [
>     "src/**/*.ts",
>     "test/**/*.ts",
>     "typings/**/*.ts",
>     // etc
>
>     // if you have a mixed JS/TS codebase, don't forget to include your JS files
>     "src/**/*.js"
>   ]
> }
> ```

In your case, you can either create a custom (`tsconfig.eslint.json`) file or adding the `include` rule in the existing one to match all the needed files.

Comment: Wow, this actually worked for me.